# Why concatenating two Strings and passing it as argument does not create a new String Object?

Tags: java, string, scjp

Im studying and getting ready for a Java SE 6 certification. Im using Kathy Sierra and Bert Bates book "Sun Certified Programmer for Java 6 Study Guide". Im actually at Strings, I/O and Parsing.

They present an example of the kind of devilish String question i might expect to see on the exam:

```
String s1 = "spring ";
String s2 = s1 + "summer ";
s1.concat("fall ");
s2.concat(s1);
s1 += "winter ";
System.out.println(s1 + " " + s2);
```

> What is the output? For extra credit, how many String objects and how
>   many reference variables were created prior to the println statement?
>
> Answer: The result of this code fragment is spring winter spring
>   summer. There are two reference variables, s1 and s2. There were a
>   total of eight String objects created as follows: "spring", "summer "
>   (lost), "spring summer", "fall" (lost), "spring fall" (lost), "spring
>   summer spring" (lost), "winter" (lost), "spring winter" (at this point
>   "spring" is lost). Only two of the eight String objects are not lost
>   in this process.

My question in the title is very specific. As you can see, they say there were a total of 8 `String` objects, but, what happens at the println method call ? It is passing a String object reference as argument, so, the value of s1 plus s2 should create other String object, since its immutable, increasing the count to 9.

But (possibly even more) shouldn't the empty String (" ") between the value of s1 and s2 create other object, increasing the count to 10 ?

It counted when they did this:

> s1.concat("fall ");

So, why not this:

> s1.concat(s1 + " " + s2);

or the real one, this:

> System.out.println(s1 + " " + s2);

Comment: I'm guessing "prior to the println statement" means before the whole line, not before the println method is entered.

Comment: Keep in mind that the compiler will optimize strings (where it can) as well. If you have String s1 = "spring" + " " + "summer" the compiler will turn that into one. Not sure if the compiler is smart enough to optimize line 2 - since you've used a variable and not "spring ".

Comment: Actually,  "spring ", "summer ", "fall ", and "winter " were not created above -- they emerged from the primordial ooze.

Comment: And, of course, the two concat operations, while they create Strings, are total noise -- they have no effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of the statement with the operative word **prior**: '

`prior to the println statement`

8 `String` objects were created before (prior to) the `println` as you described.  Another 2 were created on the `println`, `" "` and `spring winter spring summer`

```
String s1 = "spring ";             // "spring" created, reference s1 changed
String s2 = s1 + "summer ";        // "summer", "spring summer" created, "summer" not saved, reference s2 changed
s1.concat("fall ");                // "fall", "spring fall" created but not saved
s2.concat(s1);                     // "spring summer spring" created but not saved
s1 += "winter ";                   // "winter", "spring winter" created, reference s1 changed
System.out.println(s1 + " " + s2); //" ", "spring winter spring summer" created, " "  not saved
```

NOTE: "created" doesn't mean created at this point in the code, just that this piece of code will ask that it be created.

Comment: Note that "spring " was not created by the above statement.  It existed at least since the class was loaded, if not before.

Comment: Wow, now i see the word "prior". I guess i have to read carefully, specially if im going to take that exam. So, i was right. There are 10 Objects. I didn't know that those String's are in the heap before the execution of that line ! Thanks

Comment: One question: if i have : "Boolean b = true; Integer i = 10; etc.", those objects are created at that point or as you two say that happens with the String literals ?

Comment: @GabrielBB - Write a testcase and dump the bytecodes with `javap` to find out.